# Linker Error LNK2019 traced back to an __stdcall I think I got the right lib - what can I do to resolve this?

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2019, stdcall, cvi

I tried to port a LabCVI Project to MSVS 2010 C++ Express. There is a line of code which reads like this:

```
if (InitCVIRTE == 0) return 0;
```

A Linker Error occurs: LNK2019  "_InitCVIRTEEx@12" - all relevant header already feature the cpp statements:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I traced the error back to these snippets, that I combined for you:

```
#define CVIFUNC __stdcall
int CVIFUNC InitCVIRTEEx (void *hInstance, char *argv[], void *reserved);
#define InitCVIRTE InitCVIRTEEx
```

To sum this up:

```
int __stdcall InitCVIRTEEx (void *hInstance, char *argv[], void *reserved);
```

This Call should be defined in the cvirt.lib - which is added to the Librarypaths (CVI2009\extlib\msvc) The Linker Error still occurs and I just don't get why.

Should the lib be added in a different way?
How can I verify that this really is the right lib?
Does the Error mean something completely different?

Comment: Could you find a definition of `InitCVIRTEEx`?

Comment: Yes, i copied my trace together - that is the statement in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the linker what libraries to link in. The search path will only tell the linker where to find those libraries.

i.e:

```
Linker Libraries:
 - a.lib
 - b.lib

Linker Search Dirs:
 C:\project_a\lib
 C:\project_b\lib
```

the linker will search both folders for a.lib and b.lib but will not link any libraries it hasnt been told about.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow just resolved it - i added cvirt.lib and cvisupp.lib direktly to the project. The error is gone now...

however i am still not satisfied because i already gave the project the path where it should look for libraries. I will add another question to stackoverflow asking what the difference is.